# Putting JSON results into a Javascript object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an application that reads the values of a Javascript object array. I would like to put some JSON into that array of objects, but I am not sure if I'm handling it correctly.

[The JSON that I am using](http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/caiAkCgZiW?indent=2)

The Javascript object array:

```
$scope.tijdvakken = [{
      begintijd: '',
      eindtijd: ''
}]
```

I am retrieving the JSON with a function and passing it to the HTML as tijdvak as shown here:

```
<div id="tijdvakken" ng-repeat="tvak in tijdvak">
        <p ng-model="tijdvakken.begintijd">{{ tvak.begintijd }}</p>
        <p ng-model="tijdvakken.eindtijd">{{ tvak.eindtijd }}</p> 
</div>
```

I can see the results on my page, but they are not being put into the object. What am I doing wrong here and would there perhaps be an easier way of putting the results into the object without HTML?

Edit:

My function that retrieves the JSON data:

```
afsprakenService.getObject = function (link){
    return $http.get(tijdvakkenmockup);
};


$scope.getTijdvak = function() {
                    afsprakenService.getObject()
                        .success(function(tijdvak) {

                            $rootScope.tijdvak = tijdvak;
                            $rootScope.alerts.push({
                                type: 'success',
                                msg: 'Retrieved'
                            });
                        })
                        .error(function(error) {
                            $rootScope.alerts.push({
                                type: 'danger',
                                msg: 'Error retrieving! ' + error.message
                            });
                        });
                };
```

Comment: No, I would like to add every JSON object as a new Javascript object in $scope.tijdvakken, so I would have an array of objects.

Comment: where are you pushing the `json` data in your array ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Are you using `$http` service from Angular? Please show the callback for your AJAX call otherwise diagnosing your problem is an exercise of divination.

Comment: I deleted my comment as I realised at that moment what you wanted lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I don't think you have a problem here, you already put the response data into rootScope.tijdvak. But I also recommend you to use $scope instead of $rootScope.

```
$scope.tijdvakken = tijdvak;
```

You can use console.log **inside success function** to see the value of JSON object

```
console.log('tijdvak', $scope.tijdvakken);
```

Comment: Yes. I logged the JSON object, binded it to my HTML and my page showed all results. I then logged $scope.tijdvakken, but it is empty.

Comment: Did you logged it inside success function? It's a promise, so you need to log inside function.

Comment: Doesn't the fact that it's showing the JSON results on my page mean the JSON data has been binded to tijdvak? The issue was that the data was not being binded to tijdvakken. I'm not sure, but I think I needed to push the data into the object somehow as it doesn't automatically bind it (correct me if I'm wrong on this?).

Comment: Yes, it does. It's simple as is. I've just changed scope variable name to "tijdvakken". You don't need to create a new object and copy values...It's a waste.

Comment: I didn't think of that. Did not know that was possible. Thank you for the advice!

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I meant by "Or alternatively, you can just point your JSON array to your new array."...........

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `ng-model` on `<p>` element. The `ng-model` is meant for form elements only. Such as `<input>`, `<select>` or `<textarea>`.

You probably want to use `ng-bind` instead.

Also in your $scope you use `tijdvakken` but in html is tijdvak as in `ng-repeat="tvak in tijdvak"`

Answer (score 0):

loop through your JSON data (which is an array of objects too) and `array.push` them into your new array.  Or alternatively, you can just point your JSON to your new array.

```
for ( var i = 0; i < $scope.tijdvak.length; i++){

   $scope.tijdvakken.push($scope.tijdvak[i]);

}
```

Comment: Why are you going to my page and downvoting every question I made? I accepted your answer first, but PanGa showed me (with code) an alternative. I will report you for abuse.

Comment: Your "questions" look fine to me.... http://stackoverflow.com/users/5589905/lok-kwan-foo